# Check if lines forming a loop

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a simple class with properties of a vertical line on a 2D Cartesian coordinate plane such as this:

```
public class VerticalLine
{
    int x, y1, y2;
    ...
}
```

Assume that Y1 can be smaller or larger than Y2, but Y1 and Y2 never contain the same value.

In runtime, I will gather a collection(List) of vertical lines in similar format:

```
List<VerticalLine> lines = new List<VerticalLine>
{
    new VerticalLine() { X=12, Y1=3, Y2=15 }, 
    new VerticalLine() { X=23, Y1=23, Y2=5 }, 
    new VerticalLine() { X=32, Y1=12, Y2=10 }, 
    new VerticalLine() { X=37, Y1=15, Y2=12 }, 
    ...
};
```

Note that there are no specific order of the lines in the list.

By drawing imaginary horizontal lines from one end of vertical line to an end of another line, I need to check that if the lines in the above list will be able to connect and form a loop. In other words, pick a line in list, connect one end to an end of another line using a horizontal line, and then to next line and so on... until the last line connect back to the original line. See image for example.

[image: connecting vertical lines to form a loop]

Note that:

- ALL the lines in the list must be used.
- The order of the `lines` list is not important in finding the loop. Any line can be the first line.
- The directions of lines are not important in finding the loop, meaning Y2 of one line may try to connect to Y1 or Y2 of the next line, as long as they share the same Y value.

In simple words, my problem is how to write a method to check if `lines` can form a loop.

My first thought of doing so will be using a recursive method to exhaustively try connecting the next line. But this way will involve a large amount of list manipulations, which can be slow. I wonder if there are 'better' way to achieve the same goal.

Comment: FYI working with geometries you should actually use a proper geometry format and use points to define your vertexes and a line should consist of 2 points.

Comment: You could perhaps start by ordering the lines in the list based on their Y values. Then you need to find pairs that have the same Y1, Y2, or Y1 = Y2 values. Those are the lines you connect horizontally. If you find 2 pairs for every line, you have a loop.

Comment: @MariusBancila just solved the problem for you. Seems to me more like an interview puzzle. It is always better to share your work and ask for assistance.

Comment: @MariusBancila I don't think it is that simple TBH. That probably would find out if there is at least one loop, but not exactly one loop. There MAY be situation with more than one loop which is not what I want to detect.

Comment: @RaviTiwari I assure you this problem is not from one of those interview puzzles or alike. It is a simplified problem from a small part of my current hobby project. My actual code involves many other things that is not really related to the above problem. Let me extract the relevant part of the code and post the simplified code up here later.

Comment: @RaviTiwari See below for what I have so far. It is not very elegant but at least it is working.

Comment: Assuming you have no duplicate (x,y) pairs, you could check for even counts. Example: 2 coordinates with (x, 1), 2 with (x, 6). And 2 with (16, y), 4 with (12, y). If all counts are even, it's fine. Works for this example, not sure if it works everywhere.

Comment: @Carra this way, you can check if there is at least one loop, but not necessarily exactly one loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working solution I have so far. It is simple but probably not the most efficient way of doing so. It is just a recursive and exhaustive method.

```
public bool CheckForLoop (List<VerticalLine> lines)
{
    if (lines == null || lines.Count < 2)
        return false;
    VerticalLine head = lines[0];
    return CheckForLoop(head.Y1, head.Y2, lines.GetRange(1, lines.Count - 1));
}
// helper method for recursion
private bool CheckForLoop(int start, int last, List<VerticalLine> remaining)
{
    if (remaining.Count == 1)
    {
        return remaining[0].Y1 == start && remaining[0].Y2 == last || remaining[0].Y2 == start && remaining[0].Y1 == last;
    }
    foreach (var next in remaining)
    {
        bool foundMatching = false;
        int newLast = 0;
        if (next.Y1 == last)
        {
            foundMatching = true;
            newLast = next.Y2;
        } else if (next.Y2 == last)
        {
            foundMatching = true;
            newLast = next.Y1;
        }
        if (foundMatching)
        {
            List<VerticalLine> remaining2 = new List<VerticalLine>(remaining);
            remaining2.Remove(next);
            if (CheckForLoop(start, newLast, remaining2))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What I don't like about this is that it requires a separate helper method for the recursion. I would be best if everything is done within the one method itself.